# Move to another activity by click on listview item, android

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to make an android app, that populate some data from sqlite database to a list view
using `ArrayAdapter`.
The list where I store data is like this:

```
private String[] allUserColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME };
```

I want to move to another activity passing the ID related to user name by click at a listview item.

I know that I should use `setOnItemClickListener` method
but actually I don't know how to do that. 
I mean how to get the `ID`, and how to set the `setOnItemClickListener` Method to make such task.
please any one can help me with a specific code ?

Comment: Its Easy You get Position onListItemClick and get That position ID from Database.....

Comment: post your custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this with this way 
first fire query like

```
 public Cursor columnValues() throws SQLException{ 

        Cursor mCursor = db.query(Player_Table,
        new String[] {Player_Name,_id},null,null, null, null, null);

        //Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select",null);
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
 }
```

then receive like this

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

cursor = dbm.columnValues();
cursor.moveToFirst();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){

    // Received values of player name 
    // from player table

    String    reciv = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.Player_Name));               
    String    P_id= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager._id));

    first.add(reciv); 
    id_list.add(P_id); 

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

//ARRAY OF ID

```
String[] _id = id_list.toArray(new 
                    String[id_list.size()]);
player.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , first));
player.setOnItemClickListener(Activity.this);
```

and then the click listener

```
@Override  
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, 
                                      long id) {
i = new Intent(Add_Modify_Delete_Player.this, 
                            ModifyDeletePlayer.class);                  
    System.out.println(_id[position]);
    i.putExtra("Id", _id[position]);
    startActivity(i);                       
}
```